# unable to understand decimal in C#

Tags: c#, literals

I try:

```
 decimal  dd = 4.12345611111111111;
 lblText.Text =  string.Format("{0:N6}", dd);
```

but I got a error `use an M suffix`

```
  decimal  dd = 4.12345611111111111m;
```

its work perfect.I  want to know what is `m` for?.Thanks for clearing my vision.
note: `lblText` is id of label control in asp.net.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't specify the suffix the default is `double` for a number with decimal separator. M specify that the literal is actually a `decimal`

Comment: +1, but i did want to add some msdn documetnation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It is a literal used for decimal type. Read more [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpNumericLiterals.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

TO display decimal value you have to append m or M.

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal d = 1.04893m;
```

The `m` stands for monetary if I'm not mistaken, the `f` for float, and the `d`, surprisingly, for double.